# Populate a ArrayList from a text file and remove forwardSlash in the desired output

Tags: java, string, split

Hi SO Experts,

Step 1 .I have created a class DVDInfo which has title,genre, leadActor with respective getters and setters as shown in the below code.

Question : I have to populate an Arraylist from a dvdInfo.txt file which has "forward slash /" and the desired output should contain the arrayList without "forward slash /".

```
------------------------------------
       dvdInfo.txt file
------------------------------------

Donnie Darko/sci-fi/Gyllenhall, Jake
Raiders of the Lost Ark/action/Ford, Harrison
2001/sc-fi/??
Caddy Shack/comedy/Murray, Bill
Star Wars/sc-fi/Ford, Harrison
Lost in Translation/comedy/Murray, Bill
Patriot Games/action/Ford, Harrison

-------------------------------------    


    import java.util.*;     
    import java.io.*;

    class DVDInfo{
      private String title;
      private String genre;
      private String leadActor;

    DVDInfo(String t,String g,String a){
       this.title = t;
       this.genre =g;
       this.leadActor=a;
   }

   public String getTitle() {
     return title;
   }

   public void setTitle(String title) {
     this.title = title;
   }

   public String getGenre() {
      return genre;
   }

   public void setGenre(String genre) {
      this.genre = genre;
   }

   public String getLeadActor() {
    return leadActor;
   }

   public void setLeadActor(String leadActor) {
     this.leadActor = leadActor;
   }

   @Override
   public String toString() {
     return "DVDInfo [title=" + title + ", genre=" + genre + ", leadActor="
            + leadActor + "]";
   }

}

public class TestDVD {
    /*
     * //access dvdInfo.txt file and populate the arrayList by removing forward slash.
     */
    public static void populateList() throws Exception {      
      BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\src\\dvdInfo.txt")));
      //read each line of dvdInfo.txt below
      String line=br.readLine();
      while(line !=null) {
          DVDInfo = new DVDInfo(t,g,a);
          // Step 1.Wanted to create a DVDInfo Instance for each line of data we read in from dvdInfo.txt file.//failed to do so
          // Step 2.for each DVDInfo Instance ,we need to parse the line of data and populate DVDInfo's 3 instance variables --no clue.
          // Step 3.Finally put all DVDInfo instances into the ArrayList--- i dont know how to proceed(no clue)       
      } 
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<DVDInfo>  dvdList= new ArrayList<DVDInfo>();
        try{
            populateList();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught"+e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.println(dvdList);
    }

}


  ------------------------------------------------------
  output of populateList should be without forward slash
  ------------------------------------------------------    

  Donnie Darko sci-fi Gyllenhall, Jake
  Raiders of the Lost Ark action Ford, Harrison
  2001 sc-fi ??
  Caddy Shack comedy Murray, Bill
  Star Wars sc-fi Ford, Harrison
  Lost in Translation comedy Murray, Bill
  Patriot Games action Ford, Harrison
```

Please help me with the code of PopulateList method in java version 1.5, I'm stuck with this.

Thanks all it worked !!! cheers to all SO Experts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**populateList()**

```
//Signature of method changed to add List<DVDInfo> as a parameter    

    public static void populateList(List<DVDInfo> info) throws Exception {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\src\\dvdInfo.txt")));
            //read each line of dvdInfo.txt below
             String line = null;
             while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //check line in loop
                String[] tokens = line.split("/");
                DVDInfo infoItem = new DVDInfo(tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2]);
                info.add(infoItem);      
            } 
          }
```

**main()**

```
//dvdList is now passed to the method.
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<DVDInfo>  dvdList= new ArrayList<DVDInfo>();
    try{
        populateList(dvdList);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("Exception caught"+e.getMessage());
    }
    System.out.println(dvdList);
}
```

**Infinite Loop Issue**

This section of the code will cause an infinite loop.

```
      String line=br.readLine();
      while(line !=null) {
          DVDInfo = new DVDInfo(t,g,a);

      }
```

This is caused because one line is read from the buffer and then a loop is executed while that line is not null.  Since a new line is never read from the buffer the line will never be null, creating an infinite loop.  This can be fixed using:

```
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) { //check line in loop

            }
```

This loop construct assigns the line from the buffer to `Strin

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source)
 at TestDVD.populateList(TestDVD.java:74)
 at TestDVD.main(TestDVD.java:88)

Comment: @KevinBowersox im still getting this error in ide eclipse.
String line != null gives a syntax error.syntax error on token !=

Comment: @Deepak, whoops that should have been String line = null; it was assignment

Answer (score 2):

Split the line on / and you should get the desired values. Try line.split("/");

Comment: i'm unable to do it in populateList() method.can you help me with the code in populate list method,can you complete the populatelist method

Comment: String[] array = line.split("/"); // this will give you the elements in the array, just pass them in the constructor.

Comment: // Step 1.Wanted to create a DVDInfo Instance for each line of data we read in from dvdInfo.txt file.//failed to do so
          // Step 2.for each DVDInfo Instance ,we need to parse the line of data and populate DVDInfo's 3 instance variables --no clue.
          // Step 3.Finally put all DVDInfo instances into the ArrayList--- i dont know how to proceed(no clue)

Comment: This should give you the idea --- 
        String line = "Donnie Darko/sci-fi/Gyllenhall, Jake";
        String[] values = line.split("/");
        for(String a : values) {
            System.out.println(a);
        }

Comment: // Step 1.Wanted to create a DVDInfo Instance for each line of data we read in from dvdInfo.txt file.//failed to do so // Step 2.for each DVDInfo Instance ,we need to parse the line of data and populate DVDInfo's 3 instance variables --no clue. // Step 3.Finally put all DVDInfo instances into the ArrayList--- i dont know how to proceed(no clue)

Comment: you have not understood my question

Comment: i want to do it for the entire file

Answer (score 2):

You have to populate the data and return the list back to your main function :

```
 public static ArrayList<DVDInfo> populateList() throws Exception { 
         ArrayList<DVDInfo>  dvdList= new ArrayList<DVDInfo>();     
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("C:\\src\\dvdInfo.txt")));
              //read each line of dvdInfo.txt below
              String line=br.readLine();


            while (( String line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                //for each line use 
                String[] tokens = line.split("/");
                DVDInfo dvdInfo = new DVDInfo(tokens[0],tokens[1],tokens[2]); //step 1 & 2
                dvdList.add(dvdInfo );//step 3
            } 
          return dvdList;
       }
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source) at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.grow(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(Unknown Source) at java.util.ArrayList.add(Unknown Source) at TestDVD.populateList(TestDVD.java:74) at TestDVD.main(TestDVD.java:88

Comment: while (( String line = br.readLine()) != null) {  use this instead of while(line !=null) { as @kevin said as it will go into infinite loop..@Deepak

Comment: im still getting this error in ide eclipse. String line != null gives a syntax error.syntax error on token !=